# Cannot read Excel files in SSIS 2008

Tags: excel, ssis, jet

I'm stuck trying to get SSIS 2008 to read an Excel file.

Yesterday, I migrated our SSIS project from 2005 to 2008, and though the upgrade said it worked, I cannot get it to read an Excel file.  I read online that I needed to upgrade the JET drivers to Office 2007 (AccessDatabaseEngine.exe), which I did.  And voila!  Everything started working!

Unfortunately today, I rebooted my machine, and everything is broke again.  Same error as before.  I've tried re-installing the JET driver, and even installed SQLExpress 2008, which I read also has the upgraded JET driver.  But to no avail.

I cannot even create a brand new SSIS project/package, add an Excel Connection Manager, pointing to a simple Excel file that I made up of just a few numbers in column A, add a new Data Flow Task, and w/in it, add an Excel source using bound to the Excel Connection Manager.  When I do something as simple as this, I get:

Unspecified Error (real helpful)
SSIS Error Code: DTS_E_OLEDBERROR
Error Code: 0x80004005
Source: "Microsoft JET Database Engine"
DTS_E_CANNOTACQUIRECONNECTIONFROMCONNECTIONMANAGER
Hresult: 0xC020801C

I don't have a 64bit PC, and I did have everything working until I rebooted my PC.
I only have Office 2003, and I have the SQL2008 Dev Tools installed.

Any help or suggestions would be appreciated.  Is there a way to get more detailed information of the failure?

Answer (score 0):

I've had more success in reading office documents on x64 environments using the newer ACE drivers:

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=c06b8369-60dd-4b64-a44b-84b371ede16d&displaylang=en

Your connection string will be something like:

Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=c:\myfile.xls;Extended Properties="Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES";

Might be worth a try!